# Common lambda function for database interaction

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I'm trying to find a good architecture for connecting to the database. It is required that the connection to the database is not repeated in each lambda function. In addition, this way will create many connections for individual lambdas instead of one common. Can I implement the structure as in the figure below, so that one lambda connects to the database, and everyone else uses its connection in its code

[image: db connection]

Comment: "It is required that the connection to the database is not repeated in each lambda function" -- Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed architecture will not work because unless your Innovation of DB Lambda is too frequent to always keep it warm and that you are storing your connection in /tmp for reusing on subsequent innovations your DB Lambda will create new connections for each invocation. Moreover if your invocations of DB Lambda create multiple containers to serve simultaneous requests then you will anyways have those many connections instead of just one

Ideal solution will be to replace the DB Lambda with a tiny EC2 instance

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Creating EC2 instance is not what I want. The task is to make the application without a server.

And what if I use a connection pool with a limited number of connections (for mysql in my case)?

Comment: It'll still not work. Because as soon as the work is over AWS is entitled to delete your Lambda container and when your Lambda gets invoked next it can be serving from a fresh container without any history of the old one. Keep in mind Lambda is for stateless compute. And the use case of connection pooling at the Lambda level is just the opposite of that

Comment: Thank you. Could you please answer which pattern is optimal for using one database from different lambdas? I need to create connection or connection pool  in each lambda? And as I understood I should to create it outside handler, that the connection was cached? This method makes it necessary to repeat the code to connect to the database in each individual lambda and this is bad I 
think. Are there other optimal ways to solve the problem?

Comment: Actually if you have to use connection pool then EC2 is the way out. If you are concerned about code repeatation then it's not a problem because you can create your DB connection util and use that accross multiple  Lambdas codebase. Because a single zip articact can contain code for multiple Lambda (unless each Lambda is a different project in your code repository).  That way you use the same zip articact to create multiple Lambdas specifying the corresponding Handler

Answer (score 0):

The DB connection can be cached in your "DB Lambda" when the Lambda stays warm. If the Lambda does not stay warm, then invoking that lambda will suffer the price of a cold lambda, which could be dominated by having to recreate a DB connection, or could be dominated by what other work you do in "DB Lambda".

How frequently you expect your Lambdas to go cold is something to take into consideration. It depends on the statistics of your incoming traffic. Are you willing to suffer the latency of recreating a DB connection once in a while or not, another consideration?

Managing a tiny EC2 instance like someone else said, could be a lot of extra work depending on whether your cloud service is a complex set of backend services, whether that service shuts down during periods of inactivity. Managing EC2 instances is more work that Lambdas.

I do see one potential problem with your architecture. If for whatever reason your "DB Lambda" fails, the calling Lambda won't know. That could be a problem if you need to handle that situation and do cleanup.

Comment: thanks for the answer.

In my case, I want to call DB lambda inside the handler of lambda 1,2 or 3. And since DB lambda has a limited timeout, it will return to the external lambda result of its work, that is, an error or a selection from the database. Is not it?